# Get List value from another notebook in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have 2 notebooks in Mathematica. I need to open nb B from nb A and get a value of some parameters (List) with known names. How can I do it without running nb B?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the functions

```
NotebookOpen[]
```

and

```
NotebookFind[]
```

but without more information about what you want to do it's difficult to be more specific than this.  I'm surprised that your searches of the Mathematica documentation didn't lead you to these functions (and their relatives) already.

Comment: Alternatively, depending on what you are doing, it might be useful to write the values to a file in NoteBookB and read them from NoteBookA. Check this out: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ReadingAndWritingMathematicaFiles.html

Comment: Well, I have tones of "B" notebooks. Each contains a lot of data including some common data, for example pwO2 = {{0, 225},{1, 50}}; . The aim is to get all these pwO2 to notebook A.

Comment: Unfortunately, exporting data is not a good way as I have too many files to modify.